# markdown files don't format properly

Tags: comments, markdown, jekyll

I am using using jekyll and markdown for the first time to build a blog site. From what I understand about markdown files, the pound key is what is used to comment lines, except it does the complete opposite for me. Anything with in all of my .md files are commented out, and the things that are supposed to be comments, are actual live text on the page. Here's what I mean: [image]

Does anyone know what the problem is? It was working properly yesterday, so I'm thinking that it may be a problem with my text editor (Atom). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I understand about markdown files, the pound key is what is used to comment lines, except it does the complete opposite for me.

Nope. Hashes used to represent [various levels of header](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header):

> Atx-style headers use 1-6 hash characters at the start of the line, corresponding to header levels 1-6. For example:
>
> ```
> # This is an H1
>
> ## This is an H2
>
> ###### This is an H6
> ```

Markdown doesn't have the concept of comments, although it does support inline HTML, so you can use HTML comments, e.g.

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

Comment: Oh I see. I got the _config.yml file confused with the markup files and thoughts something was wrong. This makes sense now that I look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Or use liquid comment `{% comment % }Your comment {% endcomment %}` which is removed when site is generated.